# Remove or dissolve concrete adhesive

Tags: concrete

Trying to remove a pea-gravel covering which is laid over concrete with adhesive.  Aprox 100 sq. ft area. Tried to scrape and way too labor intensive.  Any adhesive/glue dissolve available?

Comment: I suspect it's going to depend a lot on the specific adhesive that was used.  You might check with a local supplier of this type of application and see if they have any recommendations.

Comment: But I think the answer is going to be "No, this stuff is designed to last forever."  You'll probably need to scrape it off.  Check with you local equipment rental shop for an appropriate power scraper.  That might help you out.

Comment: I would think that the gravel wasn't added _after_ the concrete was poured, but that the pea gravel was the aggregate in the mix and that, after floating and curing for a bit, the "cream" was washed off the surface exposing the top layer of aggregate. i.e. you're trying to remove part of the concrete itself, not something added on after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to rent a electric tile chipper, I am not sure how well it will remove the epoxy pebble coating but you hold the machine and the blade cycles back and forth chipping tiles is really fast for tile. 
I have put a few of these floors and sidewalks down and know if done according to instructions this stuff is really tough, a tile chipper or an air chisel with a flat blade may be your opinions , possibly a demo hammer with a flat blade.  (You can rent the tile chipper and a demo hammer for reasonable prices at most rental stores in my area it’s worth a check to eliminate the “work” and let the tool do it.